# Why do sunchokes seem to be stunted?

Tags: sunchoke

My sunchokes that I planted back around late April seem like they've stopped growing between 3 and 4 feet, but are suckering like crazy (3rd degree) why is this? Is the growth going to the tubers I'm keeping well watered, or do they grow out in phases where they grow up a few feet, out a few inches, and back up a lot of feet while going out?

Comment: My sunchokes never suckered, and grew 8 feet tall.  Got a picture?

Comment: i guess it was my bad, I'm just very disappointed they're only 4 feet when summer is about half over right now.

Comment: If they've flowered or have flower buds, they will not keep growing Otherwise expect at least some more growth And suckering is a sign of tuber growth, and also sometimes shallow soil

Comment: @J.Musser it's suckering like tomatoes do.